# Find a minimal lcm

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Suppose $N$ positive integers, $x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_N$, satisfy $x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_N=K$, where $K$ is a positive contant.

Now, I want to know how to find the minimal $L\triangleq \text{lcm}\left(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_N\right)$, where lcm represents the least common multiple?

my thought: We assume $x_i=ab_i,\forall i$ where $a,b_i$ is some positive integers. then $a\left(b_1+b_2+\cdots+b_N\right)=K$, so $b_1+b_2+\cdots+b_N=K/a$ is a positive integer. The goal is to minimal $ab_1b_2\cdots b_N$.

I guess $K/a$ is a minimal integer such that $K/a\geq N$ and $b_i=1$ or $2$. But I don't know how to prove it.

Example 1: $K=15,N=2$. In order to satisfy $15/a\geq 2$, we set $a=5, b_1=1,b_2=2$, then $x_1=5,x_2=10$.

Example 2: $K=15,N=3$. In order to satisfy $15/a\geq 3$, we set $a=5, b_1=b_2=b_3=1$, then $x_1=x_2=x_3=5$.

Example 3: $K=15,N=4$. In order to satisfy $15/a\geq 4$, we set $a=3, b_1=b_2=b_3=1,b_4=2$, then $x_1=x_2=x_3=3,x_4=6$.

Thanks a lot for any help.

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you getting stuck? Can you solve this for $N=2$ for example?

Comment: Since when $N$ divides $K$ this minimum is $\frac KN$ for all $x_i$ equal, my guess is that we would somehow have to study each $r$ case of $K=Nq+r$. Also the minimum is never lower than the $r=0$ case.

Comment: @gt6989b, Thanks a lot. I have updated my quesiton. please check it.

Comment: @zwim, Thanks a lot. $N\mid K$ is a special case.

Answer (score 1):

For $K < N$, $L$ does not exist.

For $K=N$, let $x_i=1$ $\forall i$. Then $L=1$

For $N < K \le 2N$, let $x_i = 2$ for $1 \le i \le K-N$ and let $x_i=1$ for the rest. Hopefully you can see why this gives $L=2$

It gets harder for larger values of $K$. For $2N < K \le 3N$, you'd like to set as many as possible to $3$ and the rest to $1$ to give $L=3$ but that's not possible with all numbers. If you have to set even one of them to $2$ then you have $L=6$. Better therefore to try setting them all as $4$ or $1$ or all as $4$ or $2$ or $1$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The method seems hard to generalize to $\forall N, K$.